# jsPlumb preserve bonds between sub divs when containers have position absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jsplumb

I'm using jsPlumb, trying to make it so that any `div` (a **task**) inside an `absolute` positioned container (a **project**) can connect to other `div`s (**tasks**) inside that container or to `div`s in other containers (in other projects).

It works fine when the projects are not draggable, and therefore **not** `position:absolute;`

meaning `.item` has `position:absolute;` and `.project` does not.
http://jsfiddle.net/wwc7G/2/

The problem occurs when I make the `.project`s draggable - so they would have `position:absolute` -  what happens is the bonds between divs (**tasks**) not within the same **project** container become out of place/don't connect.

http://jsfiddle.net/wwc7G/1/ *(this is the fiddle I'm trying to fix)*

*As an example,*
When 2 projects exist and each have a task, connecting these tasks won't work correctly when the projects are draggable (`position:absolute;`)

Is there any way I could make it so that I could drag the projects while the bonds between the tasks inside the projects are still consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the container of the two DIV's which you are trying to connect are different. So you need provide a common container by including the below code:

```
jsPlumb.Defaults.Container=$("body");
```

Here is the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wwc7G/3/)

Comment: That did it! Though it only sort of works half way? :S When you move the project `div` from which the bonds have been initially created, the anchors **don't move**. But when you move the project to which the bonds were connect everything works flawlessly.